# Redis iteratively creating broken queues similar to: ["[[:failed, []], []]", []]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

"Fixed"

The problem 'went away' when I reset my server. Seems like resque stores info on the server until it can put it into redis.

Original Problem:

I'm using Resque with Redis, with Ruby on Rails.

My Redis has gone a bit mad. It's creating many broken queues.

When I click on "Stats" I get this error:

```
RuntimeError at /resque/stats/resque
can't add a new key into hash during iteration
```

I've tried `redis.flushall`, to no effect.

Here's the full list of broken queues: http://snag.gy/a3owG.jpg

```
Name    Jobs
["[[:failed, []], []]", []] 0
["[[[:failed, []], []], []]", []]   0
["[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []]", []] 0
[:failed, []]   0
[["[[:failed, []], []]", []], []]   0
[["[[[:failed, []], []], []]", []], []] 0
[["[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []]", []], []]   0
[[:failed, []], []] 0
[[["[[:failed, []], []]", []], []], []] 0
[[["[[[:failed, []], []], []]", []], []], []]   0
[[["[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []]", []], []], []] 0
[[[:failed, []], []], []]   0
[[[["[[:failed, []], []]", []], []], []], []]   0
[[[["[[[:failed, []], []], []]", []], []], []], []] 0
[[[["[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []]", []], []], []], []]   0
[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []] 0
[[[[["[[:failed, []], []]", []], []], []], []], []] 0
[[[[["[[[:failed, []], []], []]", []], []], []], []], []]   0
[[[[["[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []]", []], []], []], []], []] 0
[[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []], []]   0
[[[[[["[[:failed, []], []]", []], []], []], []], []], []]   0
[[[[[["[[[:failed, []], []], []]", []], []], []], []], []], []] 0
[[[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []], []], []] 0
[[[[[[["[[:failed, []], []]", []], []], []], []], []], []], []] 0
[[[[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []], []], []], []]   0
[[[[[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []], []], []], []], []] 0
[[[[[[[[[:failed, []], []], []], []], []], []], []], []], []]   0
failed  0
```

Here's the code to create tasks - I believe this might explain the iteration.

```
class RegistrationEmails::LeadCreatedJob
  @queue = :slow_emails

  def self.perform(application_id)

    # No check - send it when added
    application = Application.find_by_id(application_id)
    if application
      # Send email
      LeadMailer.lead_created(application_id).deliver_now

      # Queue second part of campaign
      Resque.enqueue_in(1.minute, RegistrationEmails::LeadCreatedFollowupJob, application_id)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: What is the code for RegistrationEmails::LeadCreatedFollowupJob?

Comment: Fixed now - the itterative enqueuing was a red herring